# List as function input, weird syntax

Tags: python, list, semantics

During learning **Django** framework basics I found the following piece of code. I know how does `join()` method work but frankly speaking I have no idea what's inside.

```
output = ', '.join([p.question for p in latest_poll_list])
```

Of course the result is very clear to me, but I would rather use it this way

```
array = []
for p in latest_poll_list:
    array.append(p.question)
output = ', '.join(array)
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: its called a `list comprehension` and it is very important in python ... I would suggest learning about them

Comment: List comprehension is quite good, although sometimes it is difficult to see what they do in one go, especially if they are mixed within other functions or statements.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/ has a good explanation of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [p.question for p in latest_poll_list]
```

is a list comprehension.  It is equivalent to:

```
array = []
for p in latest_poll_list:
    array.append(p.question)
```

So the code you posted will do exactly the same thing.  A list comprehension is just a more compact way of creating a list with a `for` loop.

---

FYI, you don't really need to create a list,

```
output = ', '.join(p.question for p in latest_poll_list)
```

should also work, since `join` takes in an iterable.

Comment: Even better: drop the brackets. You'll get a generator expression, which has all the awesome of a list comprehension without even building a list.

Comment: `join()` works better with a list over a generator expression.

Comment: @SukritKalra The implementation os `str.join` specifically is slightly faster, yes, but in general avoiding the list can be desirable and even if it was slower it'd be preferable as it has less clutter and is prettier.

Comment: @jh314 Im not sure thats exactly true(equivelency) ... use dis.dis to inspect the stuff actually under the hood :P